# How to numbering div?

Tags: javascript

Can you help me plz. In my code i create elements(div) with table elements in it.

When i put "blue_button" - creates a new div with table in it. The table has 5 td rows. I need to numbering only 1st rows. I mean when i put blue_button twice, the first row in first table in first div - has number 1, the second(i need) must have number 2 (for example).

I "broke my brains". Help plz.

Here is my code:

```
var unitTableTrTd_1 = [];

var unit = document.createElement('div');

var unitTable = document.createElement('table');
unit.appendChild(unitTable);

var unitTableTr = document.createElement('tr');
unitTable.appendChild(unitTableTr);

var unitTableTrTd_1 = document.createElement('td');
var td_1_p = document.createTextNode("1");
unitTableTrTd_1.appendChild(td_1_p);
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_1);


var unitTableTrTd_2 = document.createElement('td');
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_2);

var unitTableTrTd_3 = document.createElement('td');
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_3);

var unitTableTrTd_4 = document.createElement('td');
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_4);

var unitTableTrTd_5 = document.createElement('td');
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_5);

unit.id = "block";

wrapper.appendChild(unit);
```

Comment: Your content already on the page when you cooked on button, or you want to add a new piece of content and then number all of content tables?

Comment: On a web-page i have a 2 buttons, and a table in the middle of a webpage. First button(blue) create a new element div-table, called "block", right down a table in the middle of page. Second button delete last "block". I create a big table(its a document - smeta on russian). My problem was - i create a new "block" and number in first row is always 1. But i need what number is increases  on 1 every created "block"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple,

take a global variable `table_index` ( outside button click's callback )

```
var table_index = 0;
```

now on each button click's callback increment the `table_index` by 1, and use it;

```
table_index++;
var td_1_p = document.createTextNode( table_index );
```